# Apply propercase function to a substring in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Our SQL Server 2014 system has a propercase function, which works great. I'm trying to apply it to the substring with a column that has birth city, state and country combined.

For example

```
birthplace
LOS ANGELES, CA US
DALLAS, TX US
GRAND RAPIDS, MI US
```

would like it to be

```
birthplace
Los Angeles, CA US
Dallas, TX US
Grand Rapids, MI US
```

if I apply the propercase function it currently displays

```
birthplace
Los Angeles, Ca Us
Dallas, Tx Us
Grand Rapids, Mi Us
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** version - there's 2012, 2014, 2016 and now recently 2017 - so which one are you in fact referring to??

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally published it before I could add sample data. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well . . . Assuming all birthplaces have a comma and you want to `propercase()` up to the first comma:

```
select (dbo.propercase(left(birthplace, charindex(',', birthplace))) +
        substring(birthplace, charindex(',', birthplace) + 1)
       )
```

I will note that this method does not fix spelling errors, so it doesn't change "Grand Rapid" to "Grand Rapids".  ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help it definitely pointed me in the right direction. I will post what I ultimately ended up using!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up coming up with and it works exactly as I want it to:

```
    SELECT birthplace, dbo.qProperCase(LEFT(birthplace, CHARINDEX(',',birthplace))) +
    SUBSTRING(birthplace,CHARINDEX(',',birthplace)+1,LEN(birthplace))
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff's answer seems more accurate.  In the event that somehow an extra comma were to get into your data, your solution could cause loss of data between the first and last commas.